# APT FATAL -> Failed to fork

Tags: memory, cron, apt, cron.daily, fork

I saw a lot of questions regarding this, but mine seems a little different.

Here's what I receive:

```
/etc/cron.weekly/apt-xapian-index:
FATAL -> Failed to fork.
run-parts: /etc/cron.weekly/apt-xapian-index exited with return code 100
```

and

```
/etc/cron.daily/apt:
FATAL -> Failed to fork.
```

and

```
/etc/cron.daily/apt:
DB Update failed, database locked
```

I always have at least 600 MB of free RAM.
If I try to manually run `sudo /etc/cron.daily/apt` nothing happens.. the shell hangs.

What could be the problem?

**EDIT:** Ubuntu Server 14.04

Comment: `rm /var/cache/apt/arhives/lock ; rm /var/lib/apt/lock ;rm  /var/lib/apt/lists/lock`

Comment: What do these folders contain?

Comment: They will remove the lock on apt.

Comment: I removed the lock files but when I run apt-get update they're created again..

Answer (score 27):

I've seen this message a lot. In all cases, "FATAL -> Failed to fork." meant that there was not enough memory left for the apt cron job to run. Increase free memory for this cron job.

Comment: Thank you. A "reboot now" freed up my memory issue and then the standard apt-get commands got me back on track.

Answer (score 2):

None of the suggested fixes worked in my situation. I still got the error message `DB Update failed, database locked` every day from the daily cron job. But uninstalling *apt-xapian-index* package finally solved the problem. The source of that error message is in the `/etc/cron.daily/apt` script which tries to run `update-apt-xapian-index` which is provided by the *apt-xapian-index* package.

I wrote a [little blog post](http://www.porotal.org/fixing-daily-cron-db-update-failed-database-locked-error-in-ubuntu/) about the "DB Update failed" issue from my point of view.

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact same issue on one Ubuntu 14.04 VPS and not another, so I realized that I didn't have a working swap on the one that was failing.

It turns out that everything was configured correctly but that all I had to do was `apt-get install cryptsetup` and reboot.

If you're constrained by server resources like me (512 MB RAM), I feel like it would be a good idea to keep `apt-xapian-index`, it's not well-documented but I imagine that things like `apt-cache search` would run slower without it.

That may at least fix the failed to fork error, not sure if there's any alternative to removing apt-xapian-index in the case of the DB error.

Comment: I found that I also didn't have swap defined on my Bitnami server on Azure. Not sure if installing cryptsetup would help. Instead, I followed the instructions here to add a swap file:  https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/faq/linux-faq/#what-is-swap.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with `/etc/cron.daily/apt` in Ubuntu 12 and 14 arm, but running the script from the shell succeeded. I solved it thanks to https://serverfault.com/a/191051/243172 by adding the line

```
ulimit -s unlimited
```

at the beginning of the script.

Comment: You mean in crontab?

Comment: I added it to `/etc/cron.daily/apt`, @MultiformeIngegno you would add it to `/etc/cron.weekly/apt-xapian-index`. One of the -d, -m, -s options did the trick

Answer (score 1):

The reason your shell seems to hang when you run  `sudo /etc/cron.daily/apt` is the call to `random_sleep()`. If you comment it out (on my Ubuntu 14.04, it was line 425), you can at least confirm that the script works when you run it interactively.